# Regex expression and match function in text file

Tags: arrays, regex, vb.net

I have problem with my matching function actually I have to count number of lines with specific string and return line number  ,so I have one dimensional array of string that contain the unique strings of text file {33,7,77,3 23,6} and text file with the same strings in array I have read  lines of text file to array , but with duplicate of these strings ,when I use regex.match it works not bad expect when I check if line 2 contain 3 the function return True it's consider 3 in 23 as 3 , and the above explanation is just example of what I need  any help please

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()

    Dim txt As String = File.ReadAllText("e:\ii.txt")

    ' Use regular expressions to replace characters
    ' that are not letters or numbers with spaces.
    Dim reg_exp As New Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]")
    txt = reg_exp.Replace(txt, " ")

    ' Split the text into words.
    'Dim words() As String = txt.Split( _
    '    New Char() {" "c}, _
    '    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Dim words = txt.Split(New String() {" ", Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    ' Use LINQ to get the unique words.
    Dim word_query = _
        (From word As String In words _
         Order By word _
    Select word).Distinct()
    Dim stra() As String = word_query.ToArray()
    For i = 0 To stra.Length - 1
        Console.WriteLine(" " & stra(i))
    Next



    Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("e:\ii.txt")
    For i = 0 To lines.Length - 1
        Console.WriteLine(lines(1))
        Dim linecount = 0
        Dim regex As New Regex(stra(i), RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture)
        Dim match As Match = regex.Match(lines(1))

        If match.Success Then
            linecount += 1
            Console.WriteLine("linecount=  " & linecount)
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("false")
        End If
    Next

End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: The only way to get the line number with the string you want to match, is to match line breaks as well. `^(what to match)?` in multi-line mode. Each match, increment a line counter, and check if capture group is not null. Doing it this way you don't have to use an  array of lines.

Comment: Or you could simply read a line at a time, increment a counter, check for string.

Answer (score 0):

You many not have to split the text into words.  Is your word list very long? From what I understand you want the following:

1.Read a text file and return the line number for a given word or phrase.

Is the word or phrase complex? If not, why not use a the Contains extension method?

For example: 
Dim myString = "Hello World"

If myString.Contains("World") Then
 'Add line number to line count.
End if

If you are using this as an opportunity to learn regular expressions, I highly recommend "Mastering Regular Expressions" by Jeffrey Friedl.  When I first begun I invested in a program RegexBuddy, which is worth the money. But  now there are so many online regex testers now, that could be an alternative for something free.

Comment: actually I have to split it because each word consider as item in very large data-set ,and numbers of line with specific item will be as input to an equation ,in fact number of lines is more critical in my work than line 's number

Answer (score 0):

Enhance your regex with anchors. These will ascertain that the whole test string matches instead of a substring. The following code also assembles all match patterns of interest into a single regex pattern which will be used against each line of the target file:

```
Dim strall As String
strall = ""
For i = 0 To stra.Length - 1
    If i > o Then
       strall = strall & "|"
    End If
    strall = strall & stra(i)
    Console.WriteLine(" " & stra(i))
Next
strall = "^(" & strall & ")$"
Dim regexall As New Regex(strall, RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture)

'...

Dim linecount = 0
Dim match As Match = regexall.Match(lines(i)) '... was 'lines(1)', probably a typo 

If match.Success Then
'...
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is working with me thanks for all

```
Public Function countlines(ByVal st As String) As Integer
    Dim count As Integer

    Dim linecount As Integer = 0
    Dim substrings() As String = Regex.Split(st, " ")
    Dim stt() As String = {23, 7, 3}
    For i = 0 To stt.Length - 1
        'For j = 0 To substrings.Length - 1
        'Console.WriteLine(substrings(0))

        'For i = 0 To substrings.Length - 1
        'Console.Write(substrings(i))

        Dim matchQuery = From word In substrings Where word.ToLowerInvariant() = stt(i).ToLowerInvariant() Select word
        '        ' Count the matches.

        count = matchQuery.Count()
        Console.WriteLine("count=" & count)


        If count > 0 Then

            linecount += 1

        Else

            Console.WriteLine(" linecount=" & linecount)
        End If
    Next

    Console.WriteLine("linecount= " & linecount)
    Return linecount

End Function
Sub Main()

    Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("e:\ii.txt")

    For Each line As String In lines
        countlines(line)
    Next

End Sub
```